# How many more neutrons are flying around in a fast reactor vs thermal reactor?

Tags: nuclear-physics, nuclear-engineering

I'm a bit confused on the number of neutrons in a fast reactor.

So the average neutron in a thermal reactor is 0.05ev and 700kev in a fast reactor. This means fast reactor neutrons are travelling sqrt(14million) times faster or ~3700 times faster.

Now this diagram,
[image]

shows that the flux is about 100x greater. If the number of neutrons were equal, shouldn't the flux be ~3700 times higher? Does this mean the flux represents something else, or are there actually less neutrons flying around? Or something else entirely?

Comment: In order to correctly compare the fluxes levels you should insure that the density power (in w/cm3) is the same in both reactors. Does the source of your diagram give this information ?

Answer (score 0):

The units on the plot are not correct, so this plot isn't going to give you what you are looking for.  The correct units on the y-axis should be [nt cm^-2 s^-1 eV^-1].  To obtain the total flux in an energy interval, you need to integrate the curve over the energy interval.  Once you know the total flux, you need to divide by the average speed of the neutron in that interval to get the number of neutrons.

However, if you really want to compare the number of neutrons in a fast reactor and thermal reactor, you really need to make sure the neutron flux is normalized to consistent power levels. You first need to calculate a spectrum for each reactor (which is spatially and energy dependent).  To do this, you will need to convert from a continuous energy variable to "energy groups".  You then need to normalize the total flux in each reactor to a consistent power level.  After you normalize the flux, divide the flux in each group by the average speed in the group, and then sum up the neutrons in each group.  You can do the calculation, but it won't be very useful.

Instead of knowing the number of neutrons, we usually want to know the number of neutron interactions.  The number of interactions is proportional to both the number of neutrons and the energy/speed of the neutron.  Hence flux is a more natural quantity than number of neutrons.

What you will find is that for the same power level, the flux is going to be much higher in a fast reactor.  The reason for this is that the fast fission cross section is much lower, so you need a much higher flux to produce the same power level.

(sorry for the long answer)

Comment: What I would ultimately like to do is compare the environments inside the two reactors. So if we assume U-235 in a thermal and U-238 in fast. Then the difference in reaction is ~1/50,000. 400barn at 0.05ev and 0.01barn at 1MeV

So if we imagine 3500 faster fast neutrons. Then you would need ~15x more neutrons to reach the same effectiveness as thermal reactions.

Comment: You are not including the speed.  For the same power, a fast neutron is going to be ~10^4 more effective in creating a fission, therefore you will need 10^4 more thermal neutrons. Accounting for the packing fractions (number densities), microscopic cross sections, and neutron speeds, I think there will be about 20x more thermal neutrons than fast neutrons.